# SSIS onError script task to send email - include exception details

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package where I have created a Script task on the OnError event to send an email alerting users to the fact that an error has occurred.

This works fine but what I would like to do is include in my email body the exception message that caused the event handler to fire. How can I get access to the exception inside the script task?

Current script body:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
    /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
    /// To open Help, press F1.
    /// </summary>
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {                
            string mailBody = "<p>XXXX package has failed.</p><p>Please investigate.</p>";
            string mailFrom = Dts.Variables["MailFrom"].Value.ToString();
            string errorMailTo = Dts.Variables["ErrorMailTo"].Value.ToString();                

            string smtpConnectionString = (string)(Dts.Connections["SMTPConnectionManager"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction));
            string smtpServer = smtpConnectionString.Split(new char[] { '=', ';' })[1];

            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
            var message = new MailMessage(mailFrom, errorMailTo, mailSubject, mailBody) { IsBodyHtml = true };

            // TODO append exception message to the mail body.

            smtpClient.Send(message);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                message = message + " " + ex.InnerException.Message;
            }

            Dts.Log("Error email sending failure - " + message, 0, new byte[0]);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            throw;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically stored in the @[System::ErrorDescription] variable, which you will need to map as read only to access.

You can also use @[System::ErrorCode], but SSIS error codes are generally not very helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have literally just found that variable. Site here has been up and down for me today so just updating!